# How do I get to know what part of a REGEX was activated?

Tags: javascript, regex

According to the following code example:

```
var s = "This., -/ is #! an $ % ^ & * example ;: {} of a = -_ string with `~)() punctuation";
var punctuationless = s.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g,"");
var finalString = punctuationless.replace(/\s{2,}/g," ");
```

Given a random input 'var s',

**How do I know which character was removed in the final string?**

If I could collect the detected character in a variable, it would be awesome.

Comment: maybe you could try out the regex [here](https://regex101.com/) to see some insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The replacement argument to [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_the_replacement) can be a function. You can use that to collect the matched substrings into an array:

```js
var s = "This., -/ is #! an $ % ^ & * example ;: {} of a = -_ string with `~)() punctuation";
var removedMatches = [];
var punctuationless = s.replace(/[.,\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}=\-_`~()]/g, (match) => {
  removedMatches.push(match);
  return "";
});
console.log("These matches were removed:", removedMatches)
```

Comment: And `match.index` gives you the characters position in the original string, if you need that.

Comment: Good one, I actually need that too!! haha

Comment: @sg3s - Do you mean the second argument after `match`?

Comment: @Rayon I suppose, yes. I didn't realise it was also given as an argument in that function. 
(just checked the MDN docs and there is more complexity to the arguments if you use capture groups though)

Comment: @sg3s There is no "also". The first argument is a plain string without an `index` property. Try it: `'foo'.replace(/o/g, (match) => { console.log(match.index); return 'a'; })`